# How to delete pixels without having to click multiple times?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If I try to delete some pixels, then I select rubber tool and set hardness to 100%. However, I still have to click about 4-5 times at a pixel so that it completly removes and turns to alpha.

Why is this the case and how can I solve it?

It does still not delete all inside my circle on one click , even if everything is on 100%
[image]

Comment: Due to slight inaccuracies with Wacom devices, it's possible multiple clicks are needed so the tablet actually reads movement. I know that for a single pixel, I need to tap and wiggle the stylus a little, not just tap. -- All depends on the actual driver version from Wacom though. Some versions are better than others.

Comment: I only use mouse, but thank you, maybe someone else will find this helpful sometimes!

Comment: Maybe it's an inaccuracy in Photoshop and not the Wacom device after all. I just assumed it was Wacom since I've been using that for years.  I'd at least try wiggling the mouse a little with the button held down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like either the Flow or Opacity has been reduced. Make sure both are at 100% and then it should work on a single click if you also have the hardness set to 100%.

*update*:

Given the new comments and screenshot **change your Eraser's mode from Brush to Pencil** and then it will work how you want it to.

Comment: @Black updated my answer for you, think that'll solve your problem